# SolrCloud load-balancing

Tags: solr, load-balancing, solrcloud

i'm working on a .NET application that uses Solr as Search Engine. I had configured a SolrCloud installation with two server (one for Replica) and i didn't split the index in shards (number of shards = 1). I have read that SolrCloud (via Zookeeper) can do some load balancing, but i didn't understand how. If a call a specific address where an instance of solr is deployed, the query appears only on the logs of that specific server.

On the documentation of SolrCloud i've found that:

---

Explicitly specify the addresses of shards you want to query, giving alternatives (delimited by |) used for load balancing and fail-over:

http://www.ipaddress.com:8983/solr/collection1/select?shards=www.ipaddress.com:8983/solr|www.ipaddress.com:8900/solr,www.ipaddress.com:7574/solr|www.ipaddress.com:7500/solr

---

I'm wondering if i can use this notation to force load balancing also if a have an entire index (only one shard) and in that case how the load-balancer works.

UPDATE: I've tested this solution and it works. Adding the various shard addresses in the field "shards" separated by the character "|" forces Solr to call the internal load balancer (LBHttpSolrServer) that performs a simple round robin balancing.

Thanks for your help.

Regards,
Jacopo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've tested this solution and it works. Adding the various shard addresses in the field "shards" separated by the character "|" forces Solr to call the internal load balancer (LBHttpSolrServer) that performs a simple round robin balancing.

Answer (score 1):

Since you only have a single shard, the server that is receiving the request will respond with the result, it will not perform another request to the *other* replica when it has the data locally. The Java CloudSolrServer client connects to ZooKeeper and knows which servers are up or down and will perform load balancing appropriately across all active servers. I don't believe there are any ports .NET ports available for this specific client.